# the \tkzGetAngle and \tkzAngleResult, precision

Tags: tkz-euclide

How can you specify the precision of the angle and using the absolute value of the angle in 
° ' and "

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (M) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A) at (canvas polar cs:angle=80,radius=4cm) ;
\coordinate (B) at (canvas polar cs:angle=-40,radius=4cm) ;
\coordinate (C) at (canvas polar cs:angle=30,radius=4cm);
\coordinate (D) at (canvas polar cs:angle=125,radius=4cm);
\coordinate (E) at (canvas polar cs:angle=200,radius=4cm);
\coordinate (F) at (canvas polar cs:angle=245,radius=4cm);
\draw (M) circle (4cm);
\draw (B) -- (A) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (D) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (E) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (F) -- (C);
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F,M)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\tkzLabelPoints(B,C,M)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](D,E,F)
\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](B,A,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](B,D,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](B,E,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](B,F,C)
%\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](B,A,C){$\alpha$} 
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](B,D,C){$\beta$}  
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](B,E,C){$\gamma$} 
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](B,F,C){$\delta$}  
\tkzGetAngle{angleBAC}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](B,A,C){\tkzAngleResult}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem here is TeX’s precision (which is bad). You certainly can round the value, either with TeX or PGF math or `siunitx`. But if you want a precise value (for further calculation or to export it) even if it’s not an integer, you will need to use the `fpu` library or the `fixedpointarithmetic` library of PGF/TikZ. The latter uses the `fp` package.

Comment: No ; with the code of tkz-euclide. Here `tkzGetAngle` gets a wrong value. You need to use `\tkzFindAngle(B,A,C)` just before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the positive angle, you can use `\tkzFindAngle(B,A,C)`. It works for this case at least. Then you use `\tkzGetAngle{angleBAC}` to save the result in `\angleBAC`.

To round it off, you can use `\FPround\angleBAC\angleBAC{2}` (demonstrated in example 20.7 of the manual), but that is not what you're after, I see.

To get the angle on the form DD°MM'SS" I create a macro `ddToddmmss` that converts an angle from decimal degrees to that form using PGF's math functions, and printing the result. Used with `\ddToddmmss{\angleBAC}`, on the unrounded angle.

Stripping a lot of unnecessary stuff from your example (you're not even using `pgfplots`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ddToddmmss[1]{%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\deg@tmp{#1}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\min@tmp{(#1-\deg@tmp)*60}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Min@tmp{\min@tmp}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\sec@tmp{(\min@tmp-floor(\min@tmp))*60}%
  \ensuremath{\deg@tmp^\circ \Min@tmp ' \sec@tmp ''}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% code from tikz
\coordinate (A) at (canvas polar cs:angle=80,radius=4cm) ;
\coordinate (B) at (canvas polar cs:angle=-40,radius=4cm) ;
\coordinate (C) at (canvas polar cs:angle=30,radius=4cm);
\draw (B) -- (A) -- (C);
% code from tkz-euclide no ;
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\tkzLabelPoints(B,C)
\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](B,A,C)
\tkzFindAngle(B,A,C)
\tkzGetAngle{angleBAC}
%\FPround\angleBAC\angleBAC{2}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](B,A,C){\ddToddmmss{\angleBAC}}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you get 34°33'34" as a notation?

Comment: @Arne Sorry, missed that part. Not sure, I'll try.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. `siunitx` has the arc notation.

Comment: @qrrbrbirlbel sorry I didn't saw your comment