# How can I convert automatically a calculated angle in degrees minutes and seconds

Tags: pgfplots, calculations, tkz-euclide, degrees

I want to make a batterie of exercises for a part of geometry. In this document I can change the length of the triangle. It calculates the angle. But I want the angle in Degrees minutes and seconds. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-tab,tkz-euclide,pgfplots,tkz-fct,tikz-3dplot,rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows,arrows.meta,backgrounds, calc,decorations,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.text, fit,intersections,patterns,positioning,shapes,shadows,shapes.misc,through,tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
%% names of the corners
\newcommand\HR{X}
\newcommand\HS{Y} 
\newcommand\HSS{Z} 
%% length of the sides
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RZ}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RZZ}{4.4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\SZ}{sqrt(pow(\RZ,2)+pow(\RZZ,2))}

%% name of the sides
\newcommand\ZZ{$x=\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\SZ}$} 
\newcommand\ZZZ{$y=?$} %% Geef hier de naam + schuine zijde
\newcommand\Z{$z=\num{\RZ}$} % Geef hier de naam + lengte korte rechthoekzijde
% start
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/\HR};
% other points
 \tkzDefShiftPoint[\HR](0:\RZ){\HS};
 \tkzDefShiftPoint[\HR](90:\RZZ){\HSS};
% label sides
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped,below](\HR,\HS){\Z};
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped,above](\HS,\HSS){\ZZ};
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped](\HR,\HSS){\ZZZ};
% labels
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black](\HR,\HS,\HSS);
\tkzLabelPoints[above](\HSS);
\tkzLabelPoints[below](\HR,\HS);
\tkzDrawPolygon[thick](\HR,\HS,\HSS);
\tkzMarkRightAngles[size=.5](\HS,\HR,\HSS);
\tkzFindAngle (\HSS,\HS,\HR)  \tkzGetAngle{hoekY}
 \FPround\hoekY\hoekY{0} %
\tkzLabelAngle(\HSS,\HS,\HR) {\ang{\hoekY}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129927/the-tkzgetangle-and-tkzangleresult-precision/129929#129929

Comment: @AlainMatthes thank you very much for helping to remember my own questions! Maybe this question can be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Euclidean geometry, all angles are between 0 and 180 degrees.  Longitude is divided into East and West rather than positive and negative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% includes pgfmath

\newcommand{\ancient}[1]% #1 = angle in degrees (text with decimals)
{\bgroup% use local names
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tempb}{mod(#1,180)}% angle between -180 and 180
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tempa}{ifthenelse(\tempb>0, \tempb, 360+\tempb)}% angle between 0 and 360
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\degrees}{int(\tempa)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tempb}{(\tempa-\degrees)*60}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\minutes}{(int(\tempb)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\seconds}{int((\tempb-\minutes)*60}%
  {\degrees} degrees, {\minutes} minutes, {\seconds} seconds
\egroup}

\begin{document}
  \ancient{5.33}
  
  \ancient{-400}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement this in with the automated calculated angle

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @John Kormylo[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-tab,tkz-euclide,pgfplots,tkz-fct,tikz-3dplot,rotating} 
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows,arrows.meta,backgrounds,calc,decorations,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.text,fit,intersections,patterns,positioning,shapes,shadows,shapes.misc,through,tikzmark}

\newcommand{\ancient}[1]% #1 = angle in degrees (text with decimals)
{\bgroup% use local names
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tempa}{mod(ifthenelse(#1>0, #1, 360+#1),360)}% angle between 0 and 360
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\degrees}{int(\tempa)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tempb}{(\tempa-\degrees)*60}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\minutes}{(int(\tempb)}% \minutes already used
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\seconds}{int((\tempb-\minutes)*60}%
  \ang{{\degrees};{\minutes};{\seconds}}
    \egroup}


 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
%% names of the corners
\newcommand\HR{X}
\newcommand\HS{Y} 
\newcommand\HSS{Z} 
%% length of the sides
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RZ}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RZZ}{4.4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\SZ}{sqrt(pow(\RZ,2)+pow(\RZZ,2))}

%% name of the sides
\newcommand\ZZ{$x=\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\SZ}$} 
\newcommand\ZZZ{$y=?$} %% Geef hier de naam + schuine zijde
\newcommand\Z{$z=\num{\RZ}$} % Geef hier de naam + lengte korte rechthoekzijde
% start
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/\HR};
% other points
 \tkzDefShiftPoint[\HR](0:\RZ){\HS};
 \tkzDefShiftPoint[\HR](90:\RZZ){\HSS};
% label sides
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped,below](\HR,\HS){\Z};
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped,above](\HS,\HSS){\ZZ};
\tkzLabelSegment[sloped](\HR,\HSS){\ZZZ};
% labels
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black](\HR,\HS,\HSS);
\tkzLabelPoints[above](\HSS);
\tkzLabelPoints[below](\HR,\HS);
\tkzDrawPolygon[thick](\HR,\HS,\HSS);
\tkzMarkRightAngles[size=.5](\HS,\HR,\HSS);
\tkzFindAngle (\HSS,\HS,\HR)  \tkzGetAngle{hoekY}
 \FPround\hoekY\hoekY{5} %
\tkzLabelAngle(\HSS,\HS,\HR) {\ancient{\hoekY}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```